# print_r causes page to refresh?

Tags: php

This is very bizarre and I have spent quite a while trying to figure out why the pages I was testing kept refreshing when they weren't supposed to. I finally narrowed it down to when I deleted the print_r($_SESSION['boosters']) code it quit refreshing. When the print_r is there it refreshes. You can test this yourself at http://prayerpond.com/posttest2.php (just keep manually refreshing the page and look at the counter).

Take a look at the counter displayed at the beginning of the page. If it skips a number then it is refreshing the page once it gets to the print_r.

Here's the code for the counter at the beginning of the page:

```
$_SESSION['counter']++;
echo $_SESSION['counter'];
```

Here's the rest of the code (I deleted everything else that was unnecessary to recreate the problem):

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/start.php");


// PRE-HEADER PROCESSING

unset($_SESSION['boosters']);

$_SESSION['counter']++;
echo $_SESSION['counter'];

$sql = "SELECT prayers_views_likes.*, prayers.postid, prayers.privacy, prayers.username
       FROM prayers_views_likes 
       LEFT JOIN prayers ON prayers_views_likes.postid = prayers.postid 
       WHERE prayers_views_likes.type = 'answer' 
       and prayers.privacy != 'hidden'
       and prayers.username != 'hoodleehoo'
       and prayers_views_likes.adj_ratio > 0
       ORDER BY prayers_views_likes.adj_ratio DESC, prayers_views_likes.views DESC
       ";
$_SESSION['boosters'] = send_query($sql);


print_r ($_SESSION['boosters']); //DELETE



// END PRE-HEADER PROCESSING

?>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is driving me NUTS! Anyone know what on earth is causing this?

Comment: How does the ```send_query``` function look like?

Comment: It just connects and sends the query with mysqli. Nothing strange there. I use it all the time.

Comment: function send_query($sql) {
$temprows = array();
global $conn;
connect();

$result = $conn->query($sql);
    
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $temprows[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
$conn->close();

return $temprows;
}

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: what does start.php look like?

Comment: Sounds like your database has some XSS in it or a meta refresh tag or similar that is being output to the page via `print_r`. Run that query against your database and check the results without being in a webpage to test.

Comment: start.php is just the required_once files with the functions defined

Comment: I ran the query and you can see a picture of the results at http://prayerpond.com/temp.png It's a bunch of dummy data

Comment: I tried your posttest2.php page, it redirected to index.php and wanted me to login. How do I see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($_SESSION['boosters'], true)) . '</pre>';
```

Giving a `true` second argument to `print_r()` makes it return the formatted string instead of outputting it directly. Then `htmlentities()` will encode any HTML syntax in the result -- there's probably some HTML or Javascript that's causing the refresh. I also put it inside `<pre>` so that the formatting will be retained.

Comment: I tried replacing the print_r with what you suggested and it didn't seem to affect the problem.